# B2C Custom policy access token causing 401 Respsonse

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am creating a custom signup signin policy in Azure B2C and am successfully able to get an access token using Msal.js in my Angular front end. When I try to send a request (with my jwt access token) to my .Net Core backend using authorization with B2C, I get a 401 response. I have a signup signin policy that uses the standard workflow and a request using its access token works fine. I compared the attributes on the tokens and it looks like the oid claim is missing from the custom policy token. (All of the other claims seem to be optional.) Here is a comparison of the tokens:

Broken custom policy token:

```
{
 aud: "..."
   azp: "..."
   exp: 1565534473
   given_name: "..."
   iat: 1565530873
   iss: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../v2.0/"
   name: "Aaron"
   nbf: 1565530873
   nonce: "001f61ed-61c7-4fac-b613-4a5a4e1c134e"
   scp: "read"
   sub: "..."
   tid: "..."
   ver: "1.0"
```

}

Working access token

```
{
   aud: "..."
   azp: "..."
   country: "United States"
   emails: ["..."]
   exp: 1565542145
   given_name: "..."
   iat: 1565538545
   iss: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../v2.0/"
   name: "..."
   nbf: 1565538545
   nonce: "ffd00fe6-dd02-4de1-ae06-8d6b6f0c8a81"
   oid: "..."
   scp: "read"
   sub: "..."
   tfp: "B2C_1_DefaultSignInSignUp"
   ver: "1.0"
```

}

Is it necessary to have that oid claim? If so how do I add it to my custom policy (TrustFrameworkBase.xml)? Are there any other ways to get around this 401 response?

Comment: Hi，I agree with @Chirs words. The custom policy is managed by you. So you need to create a policy key by yourself. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom.

Answer (score 0):

This might be occurring because tokens that are issued for a built-in flow are signed with a different key than those that are issued for a custom policy.

(The signing key for a built-in flow is managed by Microsoft. That for a custom policy is [managed by you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom#add-signing-and-encryption-keys).)

Ensure your backend API is referring to the `/.well-known/openid-configuration` endpoint for the custom policy rather than that for the built-in flow.